# Toggle display style when clicking on input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to display a dynamically generated list as long as my this particular input filed is active but as i click outside the input box list should get hidden. as you run the snipped the list is displayed regardless of whether the input field is focused or clicked on or not, i want it to be hidden when it is not focused.

so far I have tried to implement it but this is not working

```js
$("#pickup input").click(function() {
  var num = $(this).find("ul.suggestbox").length;
  if (num > 0) {
    $(".suggestbox ul").toggleClass("clickdisplay");
  }
});
```

```css
.suggestbox {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clickdisplay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field" style="width: 30%">
    <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i>
    </label>
    <input id="pickup" placeholder="location" type="search" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
  <ul class="suggestbox" id="sub_navlist">
<li> option 1 </li>
<li> option 2 </li>
<li> option 3 </li>
<li> option 4 </li>
<li> option 5 </li>
<li> option 6 </li>
<li> option 7 </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please fix your code and add some content to suggesbox. Assign the "search" event handler in the jQuery and add the actual function. I suggest you do NOT call it search since window.search is an existing function

Comment: edited my post since that function was not relevant to this question i removed it

Comment: sorry i cant write the function, for the sake of make snipped work, i'll make a mock list

Comment: now if you run the snipped that list is displayed even when I am not focused on the input field, all i want is that list to be hidden when I am not focusing on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(this) is not what you think it is.

I think you meant to do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pickup").on("focus", function() {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".input-field").find("ul.suggestbox");
    $list.toggle($list.length > 0); // show it if it is not empty
  }).on("blur", function() {
    var $list = $(this).closest(".input-field").find("ul.suggestbox");
    $list.hide(); // hide this list
  }).focus();
});
```

```css
.suggestbox {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top:-3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field" style="width: 30%">
    <label class="label-icon" for="pickup"><i class="material-icons">search</i>
    </label>
    <input id="pickup" placeholder="location" type="search" autocomplete="off" required>
    <ul class="suggestbox" id="sub_navlist">
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
      <li>option 3</li>
      <li>option 4</li>
      <li>option 5</li>
      <li>option 6</li>
      <li>option 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please note the `for="pickup"` on the label too

Comment: sorry but both answers are equally correct cant decide

Comment: Mine is the simplest and allow more sets of divs :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the focus and blur events:

```js
$("#pickup").on('focus', function() {
  var num = $(this).closest('form').find("ul.suggestbox").length;
  if (num > 0) {
    $(".suggestbox").addClass("clickdisplay");
  }
});
$("body").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('ul.suggestbox,#pickup').length == 0) {//check if the element selected is the input or the list
    var num = $("ul.suggestbox").length;
    if (num > 0) {
      $(".suggestbox").removeClass("clickdisplay");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.suggestbox {
  overflow: hidden;
  height:0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  max-width: 170px;
  margin-top:0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clickdisplay {
  display: block;
  height:auto;
}
body {
  height: 400px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field" style="width: 30%">
    <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></br>
    </label>
    <input id="pickup" placeholder="location" type="search" autocomplete="off" required>
  </div>
  <ul class="suggestbox" id="sub_navlist">
    <li>option 1</li>
    <li>option 2</li>
    <li>option 3</li>
    <li>option 4</li>
    <li>option 5</li>
    <li>option 6</li>
    <li>option 7</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I (also)suggest adding a `$(document).on("click",function(e) {` and interrogate the e.target for not being the input field

Comment: @mplungjan another option that i first thought but this seems more elegant to me :)

Comment: the problem is that we do not know what the function does onkeyup and OP does not want to tell us. If it alerts or shifts focus, then your focus/blur is in trouble

Comment: i have edited the post, and this is how it is looking currently as you run the snipped, what i want is that list to hide when i click somewhere else from the input field, sorry for incomplete post

Comment: thanks @madalinivascu  this works like a charm, but can you please if possible to align it, such that it appears just below the search box, i also want that space b/w that list and input box to disappear, will really appreciate it.

Comment: See my answer. I put the UL inside the div and only toggle the list that belongs to the input field

Comment: @warl0ck you simply need some css style added see updated answer

Comment: @madalinivascu sorry if you misunderstood it, but what i want is something like google suggestion list that appears just below the input text field

Answer (score 1):

You can catch click event on document and if `#pickup` is active, show list:

```js
$(document).on("click",function() {
var num = $("ul.suggestbox").length;
  if (num > 0) {
    $(".suggestbox").toggle($("#pickup").is(":focus") || $(".suggestbox").is(":hover"));
  }
});
```

```css
.suggestbox {
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 1px 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field" style="width: 30%">
    <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i>
    </label>
    <input id="pickup" placeholder="location" type="search" autocomplete="off" required onkeypress="somefunction(platform, 'pickup')">
  </div>
  <ul class="suggestbox" id="sub_navlist"><li>item1</li><li>item2</li></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: lets say we want to navigate to different page what happens to the menu?

Comment: @madalinivascu are we talking about the same question?

Comment: you realize that the toggle triggers for any object you click don't you?

Comment: This is clever :)

Comment: @madalinivascu  thank you. Didn't test it completely. changed script. now It seems to work right.